# El mensaje del formulario de contacto no se redirige del CPanel a Gmail

Tags: wordpress, formularios, email, wordpress-plugin

Estoy probando la configuración de través del dominio y hosting que posee la empresa donde hago unas configuraciones, ya pude lograr agregar el correo que se cree en el CPanel en una cuenta normal de Gmail, pero ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Si envío un correo a través de las plataformas de Gmail llegan sin
   ningún problema, y puedo responder.
2. Si envío un correo desde el servicio que esté disponible a través
   del CPanel, llega a su destino y se puede responder sin ningún
   problema.

El problema está en lo siguiente, si envío un correo a través de un formulario de contacto en la página web usando el complemento **Contact Form 7**, este llega a la bandeja de entrada en el servicio del CPanel, pero no es redireccionado a la bandeja de Gmail.

El problema a solucionar seria:

¿Cómo redirecciono el mensaje que llega a la bandeja del servicio de correo en el CPanel a través de el formulario de contacto a la bandeja de Gmail?